# A dot inside #define

Tags: c++

I have class like below

```
#include <iostream>

#define Gb MemorySizeUnit.Gb
#define Mb MemorySizeUnit.Mb
#define Kb MemorySizeUnit.Kb

using namespace std;

enum MemorySizeUnit {Gb, Mb, Kb};

class Test
{
  private:
  MemorySizeUnit memSizeUnit;
  int memorySize;

  public:
  void setMemory(const int memSize, MemorySizeUnit unit);
 }
```

and i want to be able to do something like

```
Test test;
test.setMemory(20, Gb);// as opposed to test.setMemory(20, MemorySizeUnit.Gb)
```

Compiler does not like that in #define, i have a "."

Comment: Uhh, you don't need a `#define` for this, enum members are in the global namespace already. All you need is: `test.setMemory(20, Gb);`

Comment: Isnt MemorySizeUnit.Gb in global namespace or is Gb in global namespace ?

Comment: @Jimm `Gb` is in the global namespace. `MemorySizeUnit.Gb` does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `#define` altogether, enum values are placed in the outer namespace automatically.  It's not like C# or Java where the enum values have to be accessed through the enum name namespace, absnet a `using`-like declaration.

Comment: Thanks for referring to Java. I am transitioning from Java to C++

Comment: C++ recently added `enum class { }` which behaves more like Java. In that case you would write `MemorySizeUnit::Gb`.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with having a dot in a macro expansion, the error comes from the fact that when the macro is expanded in the definition of your enum it results in an invalid enum definition.

```
enum MemorySizeUnit {Gb, Mb, Kb};
```

expands to:

```
enum MemorySizeUnit {MemorySizeUnit.Gb, MemorySizeUnit.Mb, MemorySizeUnit.Kb};
```

which isn't what you want.

Comment: +1 for spotting the recursive expansion. Personally, I would've missed it.

Comment: @ATaylor: There's no recursive expansion (the pre-processor won't do this in any case), it's just that the expansion doesn't ever result in valid code.

Comment: Is that so? Well, either case, +1 deserved (and I made a fool of myself once again :D)

Comment: Very interesting, so does pre-processor only makes one pass ? If not, the above would result into recursion...

Comment: @Jimm: The preprocessor will, in general, expand macros in macro replacements but won't expand instances of the macro currently being replaced.